# Hide Battery/AC icon in Windows 7 taskbar if laptop is plugged in

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, battery, notifications

In Windows XP, it used to be rather easy to configure the battery icon's behavior. If the laptop was plugged in the AC outlet, the icon would be hidden. When the laptop was on battery power, the icon would show itself again.

I don't know how to replicate this behavior in Windows 7. Have they removed this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The status icons for Battery, Network and Sound are static in both Windows Vista and 7. I am not aware of a third party app that would simulate this behavior as these icons have also been separated from the normal task-bar icons.